# debugging a sharepoint baselayoutpage

Tags: sharepoint, debugging, sharepoint-2007

is it impossible to debug? I am running 64-bit Windows Server Enterprise, and trying to debug my solution on Sharepoint which includes a dll that has baselayoutpage pages. When I try to atttach the process to the Visual Studio debugger (VS2008) it says break points will not be hit. I have been pulling my hair out on this one, I have tried manually locating the module in debug and specifying the pdb file, but that doesn't work. i have even tried redeploying several times. There is the VSeWSS DebugReDeploy configuration I use to reploy the assembly onto the Sharepoint site.But always ends up that I am unable to debug, I have tried many things! If anyone would know why please let me know?

Comment: there is the w3wp process running under a different login, not sure if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, I had to goto the project properties in solution explorer and goto the build options and click advanced from there select all configurations and select debug info as All... I hope I told it correctly, I am saying it from my memory